# How do you insert and retrieve an array value out of a MySQL database with PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, arrays

So I have a PHP array "$shared" with values [0, 1, 2] (I'm just using this as an example).
I want to insert and retrieve this array from my  MySQL database, but its not working.

Currently I'm using this code to insert it:

```
mysqli_query($dbhandle, "INSERT INTO table (arraytest) VALUES ('$shared')");
```

And after the above code the value in 'table' in column 'arraytest' is 'Array' instead of [0, 1, 2] or however an array should look like in a MySQL database.

After inserting the array into my database, I want to retrieve it, and am currently using this code:

```
$id='2';

$result = mysqli_query($dbhandle, "SELECT arraytest FROM table");

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {

$shared=$row{'arraytest'};

if(in_array($id, $shared)){

    echo 'Value is in the array. Success!';

}

}
```

I did some researching online, and have not found a way to do this specifically.

I want to insert a PHP array() into one cell in the table in the database,
and then I want to retrieve that array from the database and check if a certain value is in the array which I previously inserted into the database.

P.S. I am not trying to retrieve an entire column of values from the database as an array. This is what i have found on google when i search for an answer, and it is not what i want to do.

Comment: generally not recommended, you should be storing each value of the array separately. but if you *must* use serialise()

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have to question why you would want to do this, but the simplest answer is to serialize the array.

```
"INSERT INTO table (arraytest) VALUES ('" . serialize($shared) . "')"
```

Then you can use `unserialize` when you retrieve it from the database

---

You should properly parameterize your queries to prevent injection or errors.

Comment: Also I want to use an array because the array could contain up to 30 values, and I don't want to have 30 columns in my table.

Comment: @edwardtyl google "prepared statements."  Instead of having 30 columns what you should do is break this out into another table that joins on this table and create 30 rows

Comment: @ExplosionPills Would that be a better option than just serializing it? Because serializing seems a lot easier.

Comment: @edwardtyl I think it would be, but it depends on how the data is to be used.  Storing it in an array makes it very hard to use and manipulate with MySQL itself; you practically have to use PHP if you want to do any work on the values of this array

Comment: @ExplosionPills Well I'll use serialize in that case since I only plan to use php, and this is for a chat program in which the array contains the id's of every person that can see the post (which is in a seperate column in the same row). Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Or use json_encode() to make a JSON string out of your array (and json_decode() to convert it back). That will give you a more platform-independent, aka future-proof representation of your data. Besides this will result in slightly less characters stored in your DB.

I met a couple of cases where data was represented with way, usually 'additional' information for records that was hard to press into the schema is it was changing record by record. It's a pragmatic solution, though not a very nice one. In particular, you'll have a hard time querying the information stored in this array without reading the entire table into memory.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot insert PHP arrays into a db. Your problem is this:

```
$arr = new Array(1,2,3);
echo $arr; // prints "Array"
```

When using arrays in a string context in PHP, you just get the word "Array", not the contents of the array. You have to run a loop on the array to insert each individual value, e.g.

```
foreach($arr as $val) {
   INSERT INTO yourtable VALUES ($val)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

While storing an array like this isn't recommended, the best way is to use serialize and unserialize (for getting the data back from the database). However, I think you should just place each value is a separate cell using a foreach loop...

Answer (score 0):

How to retrieve the array data from the database? I am inserted the array data using PHP implode function.

```
$val=implode(',',$val);
```

I am inserted into the MySQL database.